# Are function declarations non-static?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, closures

I'm not sure if I phrased the question accurately, but up to this point I had always assumed a function declaration in javascript was 'set in stone'.

When I tried to better understand closures (mimicking a simplified version of React's useState), I became unsure of where the 'x' in the following code block was being stored in memory:

```js
function useState () {
    let x = 0;
    return [function() { console.log(x) },function (y) { x = y}];
}

const [getX, setX] = useState(); 
getX()
setX(1)
getX()
```

So while the useState function returns a getter and a setter as variables "getX" and "setX", where exactly is "x" being stored? In the original declaration of useState? What am I missing here?

Comment: `let x` - there's your `x`

Comment: right, but does that mean it is essentially rewriting itself inside the original function declaration?

Comment: it means that x stores the value when `function (y) { x = y}` is called .... which is `setX`

Comment: I guess I'm confused about the getter/setter being able to still access an internal scope; I had always assumed closures dealt with being able to access external scopes.

Comment: the "getter" and "setter" **are** the functions returned  by `useState`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function (or any block) runs, a new [Environment Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-environment-records) is created, which is essentially a mapping of variable names *used inside that block* to the values they contain. If the variable names can be referenced after the block has finished, this is what is generally called a "closure".

Every time a function runs, a new such record is created. This record closure is where your `x` gets stored. This is also why you can call your `useState` multiple times, and have the resulting be separate:

```
const [getX, setX] = useState(); // Function called; record created
const [getY, setY] = useState(); // Function called again; another record created
```

Above, since `useState` runs twice, you've created *two* environment records / closures, each with a separate binding of `x` So `getX` and `setX` close over the same `x`, and `getY` and `setY` together close over a different `x`.

If the `useState` function is never called, `x` is not stored anywhere, because the record for the `useState` function is never created.